# Extracting multiple URLs with no 'a' or 'href' tags from web page with BS4

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm making a simple program with Selenium that goes to Flickr.com, searches for the term the user inputs, and then prints out the URLs of all those images.

I'm struggling on the final part, getting just the URLs of the images. I've been using the `class_=` search to get the portion of the HTML where the URLs are. This returns the following multiple times when searching for 'apples':

```
<div class="view photo-list-photo-view requiredToShowOnServer awake" 
   data-view-signature="photo-list-photo-view__engagementModelName_photo-lite-
   models__excludePeople_false__id_6246270647__interactionViewName_photo-list-
   photo-interaction-    view__isOwner_false__layoutItem_1__measureAFT_true__model_1__modelParams_1_    _parentContainer_1__parentSignature_photolist-
   479__requiredToShowOnClient_true__requiredToShowOnServer_true__rowHeightMod    _1__searchTerm_apples__searchType_1__showAdvanced_true__showSort_true__show    Tools_true__sortMenuItems_1__unifiedSubviewParams_1__viewType_jst"
   style="transform: translate(823px, 970px); -webkit-transform:     translate(823px, 970px); -ms-transform: translate(823px, 970px); width:
   237px; height: 178px; background-image:
   url(//c3.staticflickr.com/7/6114/6246270647_edc7387cfc_m.jpg)">
<div class="interaction-view"></div>
```

All I want is for the URL of each image to be like this:

```
c3.staticflickr.com/7/6114/6246270647_edc7387cfc_m.jpg
```

Since there are no `a` or `href` trags I'm struggling to filter them out.

I tried doing some regex as well at the end such as the following:

```
print(soup.find_all(re.compile(r'^url\.jpg$')))
```

But that didn't work.

Here's my full code below anyway, thanks.

```
import os
import re
import urllib.request as urllib2
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

os.makedirs('My_images', exist_ok=True)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

print("Opening Flickr.com")

siteChoice = 'http://www.flickr.com'

browser.get(siteChoice)

print("Enter your search term: ")

term = input("> ")

searchField = browser.find_element_by_id('search-field')
searchField.send_keys(term)
searchField.submit()

url = siteChoice + '/search/?text=' + term

html = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.find_all(class_='view photo-list-photo-view requiredToShowOnServer awake', style = re.compile('staticflickr')))
```

my changed code:

```
p = re.compile(r'url\(\/\/([^\)]+)\)')

test_str = str(soup)

all_urls = re.findall(p, test_str)


print('Exporting to file')


with open('flickr_urls.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in all_urls:
        f.writelines("%s\n" % i)

print('Done')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
url\(\/\/([^\)]+)\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vG0bL3/1)

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'url\(\/\/([^\)]+)\)')
test_str = u"<div class=\"view photo-list-photo-view requiredToShowOnServer awake\" \ndata-view-signature=\"photo-list-photo-view__engagementModelName_photo-lite-\nmodels__excludePeople_false__id_6246270647__interactionViewName_photo-list-\nphoto-interaction-    view__isOwner_false__layoutItem_1__measureAFT_true__model_1__modelParams_1_    _parentContainer_1__parentSignature_photolist-\n479__requiredToShowOnClient_true__requiredToShowOnServer_true__rowHeightMod    _1__searchTerm_apples__searchType_1__showAdvanced_true__showSort_true__show    Tools_true__sortMenuItems_1__unifiedSubviewParams_1__viewType_jst\"\n style=\"transform: translate(823px, 970px); -webkit-transform:     translate(823px, 970px); -ms-transform: translate(823px, 970px); width:\n 237px; height: 178px; background-image:\n url(//c3.staticflickr.com/7/6114/6246270647_edc7387cfc_m.jpg)\">\n<div class=\"interaction-view\"></div>"

m = re.search(p, test_str)
print m.group(1)
```

Output:

```
c3.staticflickr.com/7/6114/6246270647_edc7387cfc_m.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see how that will grab what I need but I dont think Im implementing it correctly now, should the final line be this then? print(soup.find_all(re.compile(r'url\(\/\/([^\)]+)\)')))                                                  its not working for me Im afraid though

Comment: thanks! I think its supposed to be (r'url.. and not (ur'url... right? Ive put my changes above and works perfectly now anyway, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

To scrap all the png/jpg links from a page with Selenium :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.flickr.com/")
links = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML.match(" \
  "/https?:\/\/[a-z_\/0-9\-\#=&.\@]+\.(jpg|png)/gi)")
print links
```